# Css Transform Disables Percentages in Height

Tags: html, css, height, transform

Hey I got exact problem on the title. Simple as it. When I remove

```
*{transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}
```

it works.

With overflow:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ln8sw6ce/1/

Without:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ln8sw6ce/2/

EDIT[From 5.5.2014 on this bug no-longer exists.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why but

```
*{ -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); height: 100%; }
```

does work.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln8sw6ce/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Again, I have to answer my question. I don't know why transform not work with new html5 tags.
But I changed

```
header nav{}
```

to

```
.header .nav{}
```

and edit code for it, it works!

Please. Someone Explain.